# How to troubleshoot this HDD performance issue?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, benchmarking

I purchased [WD60EZAZ](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/internal-drives/wd-blue-hdd/data-sheet-wd-blue-pc-hard-drives-2879-771436.pdf) for usage in [Synology DS118](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DS118) NAS. I put around 500GB of data onto the disk, however I noticed very slow read/write performance.

I decided to run some tests on the disk directly, to make sure the network is not the bottleneck.

1. First I tried to run `dd` on the NAS directly:

```
dd if=1G.rnd of=/dev/null bs=8k
131072+0 records in
131072+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 14.0897 s, 76.2 MB/s
```

According to the tech spec, disk transfer speed should be ~180 MB/s, and I do not observe anything even close to that. The utility shows just 76 MB/s, which is **very** low. Maybe the issue is in NAS itself?

2. I decide to connect the HDD to my desktop and see how it performs as an external HDD. As I use Mac, I connected the HDD to a VMware Fusion virtual machine in [raw disk](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2097401) mode. The VM is running Ubuntu 21.10, and I use the Disks utility to perform a read test with the following parameters:

[image]

The results:

[image]

The picture is very strange. for the most part of the drive it shows speed 250-290 MB/s which is unrealistically high. For a certain fraction, it shows 90-100 MB/s which seems reasonable but not quite close to what `dd` on NAS shows. And the third part shows very inconsistent results. If I keep the HDD next to my ear, I hear that during the "fast" segment heads are not moving, while during the "slow" segment heads are moving intensively. This is confusing, because, as I understand, during the read test it reads continuous 100 MB samples from raw device (not file system), which should not involve a lot of heads moving (and this theory is confirmed on another HDD).

3. Then I use `hdparm` for a simple read test:

```
sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda1
[sudo] password for user: 

/dev/sda1:
 Timing cached reads:   23754 MB in  1.99 seconds = 11932.77 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 174 MB in  3.01 seconds =  57.80 MB/sec
```

4. Then I mount the biggest partition of HDD and perform a similar `dd` test from Ubuntu:

```
dd if=1G.rnd of=/dev/null bs=8k
131072+0 records in
131072+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 13.3885 s, 80.2 MB/s
```

Quite similar to NAS. Little bit faster due to a better CPU probably...

The files I run `dd` on are exactly the same as in NAS.

The results are very inconsistent. Here is the summary:

- NAS, dd: 76 MB/s
- Ubuntu, dd: 80 MB/s
- Ubuntu, hdparm: 60 MB/s
- Ubuntu, Disk benchmark: 90-290 MB/s

For comparison, another my 5 years-old external 2.5'' HDD demonstrates consistent ~100-120 MB/s read speed when using the above test methods.

**Now questions:**

1. I understand that HDD read speed depends on the physical location of the data and the speed can vary 2.5 times due to that. When they print 180 MB/s in the specification do they mean average or maximum?
2. How to explain 290 MB/s read speed in the item #2? Why does it vary so lot?
3. The read speed test results are pretty disappointing. Is something wrong with my HDD? Is there anything I can do to fix it? Any further testing recommendations?

Comment: At 8k block size, you will not get the maximum throughput your drive is capable of. On a 4 TB drive here, 8K/1M results in 110 MB/s / 180 MB/s. Also keep in mind that by using a file you are not (only) testing the drive but also the filesystem. // Try overwriting the disk with zeroes, then testing again. // Your drive may already have remapped regions as a result of factory testing.

Comment: According to https://nascompares.com/answer/list-of-wd-cmr-and-smr-hard-drives-hdd/ the WD60EZAZ is an SMR drive which can have somewhat curious performance characteristics which can vary over time as data is shuffled from the CMR area to the SMR area. Possibly the best you can do is give the drive some time to do its management and cleanup. These types of drives are "good" but do not necessarily behave like older drives https://www.google.com/search?q=cmr%20vs%20smr

Comment: @DanielB I do not see measurable difference between 8k, 1M or 16M block. Tested on combinations of machines and HDDs. Larger block gives maybe a slight increase in throughput.

Comment: @Mokubai that it interesting, thanks...

Comment: Performance can be particularly odd and may seem to "stall" for periods during writing, and on reading it may be that the drive is swapping between CMR and SMR zones depending on where the data is at that time. The SMR zone should be good for reading but can be slow for writing. There's also the fact that this management has some overhead in the drives on-board controller.

Comment: Note: If you intend to use a SMR drive in a RAID or ZFS configuration, DON'T. The probability of a failure during a rebuild is crazy high

Comment: My concern in this post is READ speed. As it is a home photo/video storage writing speed is not so important, but reading speed maters when you browse or skim through the content.

Comment: @greatvovan my point was that SMR drives have two areas which the controller moves data between, and after being written then data may be spread across both areas which can affect reading speed in unpredictable ways.